# Can't install EclipseCoder on Kepler

Tags: eclipse, pydev

- Eclipse Version: Kepler
- PyDev Version: 3.1

I can't install [EclipseCoder](http://fornwall.net/eclipsecoder/) on my Ubuntu 13.04 machine. The installation fails with the following error message:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software currently installed: EclipseCoder Python Support 0.2.2 (net.fornwall.eclipsecoder.pythonsupport.feature.group 0.2.2)
Missing requirement: EclipseCoder Python Support 0.2.2 (net.fornwall.eclipsecoder.pythonsupport 0.2.2) requires 'bundle org.python.pydev [1.3.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: EclipseCoder Python Support 0.2.2 (net.fornwall.eclipsecoder.pythonsupport.feature.group 0.2.2)
To: net.fornwall.eclipsecoder.pythonsupport [0.2.2]
OK
```

I already have PyDev installed from the PyDev update site. Is this plugin only bound to PyDev 1.3/PyDev 2.0. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Did you get a workaround for the Python support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PyDev version used in the plug-in was very old - I've updated the python plug-in to use the current PyDev version and pushed it as version 0.2.3 to the update site, so you should be able to install now.